# mtasc for Lion OSX?

Tags: flash, gnu-make, mtasc, swfmill

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up mtasc on my Lion OSX machine.  I'm currently trying to run a makefile script that is:

SWFMILL     := swfmill
MTASC       := mtasc

MTASCSTDLIB := /usr/share/mtasc/std

main:
    $(SWFMILL) simple src/jscam.xml jscam.swf
    $(MTASC) -v -swf jscam.swf -main jscam.as -version 8 -cp src -cp $(MTASCSTDLIB)

clean:
    rm -f jscam.swf

I'm pretty sure SWFMill is set up fine, but upon running this make file, I get:

Mikes-iMac:js $ make
swfmill simple src/jscam.xml jscam.swf
mtasc -v -swf jscam.swf -main jscam.as -version 8 -cp src -cp /usr/share/mtasc/std
Launch of "mtasc" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported.
make: *** [main] Error 2

Perhaps there is a more current version of mtasc that I should be using (that's the assumption I'm getting from the error)?  I just can't find anything online that offers much clarification on whether that version exists, or if there is another way to make this work.  I saw a fairly recent blog post about mtasc at http://www.grindheadgames.com/mtasc-permission-denied-error-fix, which makes me think it should still work on Lion since it did for them.

Thanks in advance!